# Adding pandas dataframe calculated columns like in Excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently using panda for data science purposes, which is very unoriginal, so I'm sure there's a better way than mine of adding columns to a dataframe calculated from the others, in an excel fashion.

For example, I've got a dataframe in which I've got a mass and a period, and I'd like to add a column with (M/P)^(1/3), M and P being converted in the appropriate units. I then write

```
day_sec=60.0*60.0*24.0
Msun=1.989 * 10**30
clean=reduced.dropna()
v=pd.DataFrame(clean['orbital_period'].apply(lambda x: x**(1/3.0))/clean['star_mass'].apply(lambda x: x**(1/3.0)), columns=list('v'))*day_sec/(Msun**(1/3.0))
clean.append(v)
```

Which doesn't even act like I want, and is very complicated both to write and read (here, the equation was very very simple). Any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to create a new column from existing columns, the best way to do it is something like `df['c'] = df['a'] + df['b']`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use apply at all here. You should write the new column as one vectorized operation that looks something like this.

```
clean['v'] = clean['orbital_period'] ** (1/3.0) / clean['star_mass'] ** (1/3.0) *day_sec/(Msun**(1/3.0))
```

Which looks like it can be reduced to the following:

```
power = 1/3.0
(clean.orbital_period / (clean.star_mass * Msun)) ** power * day_sec
```

Comment: Or with `pow`, something like `pow(clean.orbital_period / (clean.star_mass * Msun), 1/3.0) * day_sec` should work.

Comment: When I run your code, I get : /Users/Home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:5: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead